# Create a ListObject by passing name of a table located anywhere in the workbook with a variable

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

Here is my scenario using VBA in Excel. I have one table (table01) that contains the name of all tables in the workbook. I am trying refer to one of the tables in Table01 using ListObjects() so that I can perform operations on that table. I am getting a debug error #9 on the line noted below. What am I doing wrong on the error line?

Here is my code simplified:

---

```
Dim Table01 as ListObject 'list of all tables in workbook 
Dim Table02 as ListObject 'table selected from Table01 
Dim TableName as String 'name of table02 as listed in Table01 
Set Table01 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tTablesDetails")
TableName = Table01.TableList.DataBodyRange(SomRowNumber, SomeColumnNumber).Text

MsgBox (TableName) 'Shows table name I expected       
Set Table02 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TableName) 
'DEBUG ERROR 9 IS HERE

...rest of code
```

Comment: So, I'm guessing this has to do with the use of ActiveSheet... Do I have to tell VBA which sheet the table is on for this to work? I saw using Range to get around this would work, but I didn't understand the posts.

Comment: Yes. Below I suggest you have another column which holds the parent sheet name. Otherwise a function which loops all ListObjects in workbook and returns the parent worksheet of the matched name (assuming names don't repeat in book)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what .TableList is. It is not a method/property of ListObject AFAIK. You definitely need to declare values for someRowNumber, someColumnNumber as there is no 0,0 in the range. For the example below, you are assuming the selected table is in the same sheet as the Table01. You may need another column to hold the parent sheet if you wish to reference tables in other sheets and pull that in to (Or loop all ListObjects in workbook and test by name; assuming names don't repeat) so you have

```
Set Table02 = Worksheets("someSheetNamePulledFromTable01").ListObjects(TableName)
```

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim Table01 As ListObject                    'list of all tables in workbook
    Dim Table02 As ListObject                    'table selected from Table01
    Dim TableName As String                      'name of table02 as listed in Table01
    Dim someRowNumber As Long, someColumnNumber As Long
    someRowNumber = 1: someColumnNumber = 1
    Set Table01 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tTablesDetails")
    TableName = Table01.DataBodyRange(someRowNumber, someColumnNumber).Text

    MsgBox (TableName)                           'shows table name i expected

    Set Table02 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(TableName) 'DEBUG ERROR 9 IS HERE

End Sub
```

---

Avoid using Activesheet at all and use explicit worksheet names throughout. Perhaps have the ListObject's parent sheet name in the next column to the right:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim Table01 As ListObject
    Dim Table02 As ListObject
    Dim TableName As String, SheetName As String
    Dim someRowNumber As Long, someColumnNumber As Long
    someRowNumber = 1: someColumnNumber = 1
    Set Table01 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("tTablesDetails") '<=avoid Activesheet reference and use explicit sheet name
    TableName = Table01.DataBodyRange(someRowNumber, someColumnNumber).Text
    SheetName = Table01.DataBodyRange(someRowNumber, someColumnNumber + 1).Text

    MsgBox (TableName)                           'shows table name i expected

    Set Table02 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).ListObjects(TableName)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create ranges and get it to work and clean up my code, for example:

Dim Table02 As Range

Set Table02 = Range(TableName).ListObject.DataBodyRanege

Range doesnt care what sheet the table is on.